# Загадочный нижний отступ в блоке

Tags: html, css, ссылки, отступы

Привет. Уже день вожусь с поиском ответа на вопрос, но почти безуспешно. Решил постучаться сюда.
На сайте https://www.dropbox.com/business в **правой** части секции номер три (с изображением компьютера) расположен элемент ссылки с изображением стрелки внутри. Я не могу понять, в результате чего размер блока не ограничивается размером изображения, а имеет странный отступ на 8 пикселей вниз. Из собственных рассуждений и проб пришел к выводу, что причиной всему параметры:
`line-height: 26px, font-size: 14px`
 Но этим дело не кончилось. После попытки накодить такую же стрелку на своей странице заметил, что эти же параметры на размеры моей версии блока никак не влияют. На всякий пожарный скину и свой класс.

```
.carousel-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: right 250ms ease 0s;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.carousel-arrow img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент `img` по умолчанию имеет поведение как `display: inline-block`. Поэтому на него действует родительский `line-height`. В вашем примере у `img` установлен `display: block`, поэтому `line-height` на него не действует.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Этого не знал. Вы мне очень помогли. И как я не заметил-то.